# How can I color only one part of a glyph?

Tags: color

For the purpose of highlighting parts of typography, is there a way to colour only the particular parts of a given glyph (eg the serifs)?

For example, I would like to colour **just the long-tail of this Q**, rather than the whole glyph, in EB Garamond to show the change.

A minimum, non-working example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=Rare]{EB Garamond}
\newcommand\Qlong{\XeTeXglyph\the\XeTeXglyphindex "Q.long" \relax}

\begin{document}
    Qui  \textcolor{red}{\Qlong} ui
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! Have you seen https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/524069?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/530892 may also suggest some approaches.

Answer (score 1):

The following attempt relies on that "O" and "Q.long" without tail are almost the same.

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=Rare]{EB Garamond}
\newcommand\Qlong{\XeTeXglyph\the\XeTeXglyphindex "Q.long" \relax}

\begin{document}
    \Huge
    Qui  \textcolor{red}{\Qlong}\llap{O} ui
\end{document}
```

[image]